# Start a new activity with no transition animation in android 1.6

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, android-intent

I am aware that from API level 5 it is possible to specify a flag in the intent to prevent the normal animation being applied when I start a new activity:

```
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
```

However, my question is: is there a way to achieve the same thing in an app supporting android 1.6?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use this: `getWindow().setWindowAnimations(0);` within the `Activity` that is starting.

Comment: Thanks, where should this line go, in the activity I am starting or in the one I am starting it from?

Answer (score 51):

On the newer versions, you want to override the transition with 0,0 shortly after you start the activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, YourNewActivity.class); 
startActivity(i);
overridePendingTransition(0,0);
```

I tried this on 2.1 and 4.0.3, it worked for me.   =)

I found it in the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 6):

This solution worked for me (Android 2.2):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), YourClass.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This worked for me on 4.0.3 - not sure why it's down-voted... Perhaps because the question asked for something in Android 1.6?

Comment: It causes a reverse transition on 2.3.5

Answer (score 5):

FYI, I'm on 4.4.2 and these are the only things I found that work:

**To prevent the opening animation:** in the launching activity's onCreate(), add overridePendingTransition(0,0).

**To prevent the closing animation:** after finish(), immediately call overridePendingTransition(0,0).

These DON'T work (at least not on my 4.4.2 build): (1) calling getWindow().setWindowAnimations(0) in onCreate() (passing in a non-zero number DOES work, but that's an ugly hack since it's expecting a resId), and (2) calling overridePendingTransition(0,0) immediately after startActivity() -- animation is still present.

Answer (score 0):

put below code on onCreate of Activity:

```
getWindow().setWindowAnimations(0);
```