# Do I need to write overridePendintTransition every time I start an activity?

Tags: android

I want all my activities to have no transition animation. Do I need to write `overridePendingTranstion(0,0)` right after every `startActivity()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer , Yes you have to .

From the docs,

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: Thanks, the entering works. But my activity still fades out. Do you know why?

Comment: I didn't set any flags (I have never did, I am new)

Comment: startActivity(new Intent("Activity2"));
  overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

Comment: `overridePendingTransition(0,0);` use this method in onResume of your Activity

Comment: Thanks!! It works. But why?? Why do I have to put it in onResume()?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a style,

```
 <style name="noAnimTheme" parent="android:Theme">
   <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

and set it as theme for your activity in the manifest:

```
   <activity android:name=".ui.ArticlesActivity" android:theme="@style/noAnimTheme">
    </activity>
```

You can also define a style to specify custom entry and exit animations.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowEnterAnimation

Answer (score 0):

create your custom theme in style.xml

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

then define this theme in your manifest activity.

```
<activity
 android:name="com.packagename.activityname"
android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" ></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned,

[start-a-new-activity-with-no-transition-animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460611/start-a-new-activity-with-no-transition-animation-in-android-1-6)

On the newer versions, you want to override the transition with 0,0 shortly after you start the activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, YourNewActivity.class); 
startActivity(i);
overridePendingTransition(0,0);
```

Comment: Thanks, now fading-in is gone, but it still fades out. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want animation between activities then you need to call overridePendingTransition(0,0); every time.